# py2neo cypher query error: neo4j.SyntaxException

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I'm trying to execute a simple parameterized cypher query which actually fails due to a syntax error.

```
params = {
   "k" : k,
   "v" : v,
   "p": {
      "name": "marc"
   }
}

query = "CYPHER 2.0 MATCH (n { { k } : { v } }) SET { p } RETURN n"
data, metadata = cypher.execute(graph_db, query, params=params)

...

SyntaxException: Invalid input '{': expected whitespace, comment, an identifier, '}' or UnsignedInteger (line 1, column 12)
"MATCH (n { { k } : { v } }) SET { p } RETURN n"
```

I'm using py2neo 1.6.3 with flask.

Thanks in advance!

/Marc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters are only allowed in certain places. Try the following statement:

```
MATCH (n { k : { valueParam } }) SET { n.name = { nameParam } } RETURN n
```

Your map would contain:

```
params = {
   "valueParam " : "v",
   "nameParam " : "marc"
}
```

To state the [Cypher docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-parameters.html):

> Parameters can not be used as for property names, relationship types
>   and labels, since these patterns are part of the query structure that
>   is compiled into a query plan.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks so far. That worked, but it's not satifying my needs. Neo's Cypher docs actually say it's possible to pass dictionaries implying values AND keys. Or am I getting this wrong? Is it because of py2neo then?

Edit: I need at least SET to handle the dictionary

Comment: No, I don't expect this to be a problem related to py2neo. AFAIK, you can't specify node properties as parameters

Comment: I got it. Misread the docs on setting all properties on node where I need to specify the node and then pass the dictionary to it. Oops. Thank you anyway for your fast responses!

Comment: You can do `CREATE (n {p})` with your parameter map `p`. Or `MATCH (n {name:{p}.name}) SET n = {p}`.